# How to draw vectors?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors, torque

The images show rotational motion.Here, $r$ is the position of the particle and $F$ is the force applied on it.
Now, if I draw vectors $F_x$ and $F_y$ according to fig.2, I understand why it moves in a circular path.My confusion is in fig.1. My teacher derived the expression of torque using fig.1. What I can't understand is how $F_y$ can can help move the particle in circular path?

[image]

Comment: One thing you could do is break both F_x and F_y in Fig 1 into parts tangential and normal to the curve (i.e., the directions used in Fig 2). Then you would see that the tangential parts of F_y and F_x combined equal the F_y of the second diagram (and the normal parts sum to F_x). It's not that I can see this at a glance, but mathematically it _must_ be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of calculating torque, both the figures provide good choices. If you know coordinate of the the point where force $\vec{F}$ acts, taking components of $\vec{F}$ along directions parallel to coordinate axes, as in Fig. 1, may help. If you know the radius of the circle, taking the components as in Fig. 2 may be better.

However, it may be easier to visualize the intended circular path, at least for beginners, if the force is resolved as in Fig. 2 because then they can see the components as tangential and radial components. But, even if you are presented with Fig. 1, you can mentally resolve the component $F_y$ along tangential and radial directions. Here, I am saying to (mentally) resolve a component ($F_y$) along two perpendicular directions just to understand that there are indeed tangential and radial components of force $\vec{F}$ just like as in Fig. 2. But actually resolving a component again into components is often not useful and can lead to confusion and hence must be avoided.

Comment: Thnx for answering

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, if $F_x$ and $F_y$ are components of $\vec F$, they are usually drawn not to extend beyond the projection of $\vec F$ in that direction. E.g. the $F_x$ arrow in Fig 1 should be much shorter, and $F_y$ in Fig 2 should be much shorter.

You can choose any set of orthogonal directions and call it "$x$ and $y$," so in that sense either figure is correct, but I will say Fig 2 seems like a more natural choice for the problem, tangential and radial to the circle.

Comment: Sorry for the bad figures. I still dont understand how fig 1 make sense. But thnx for answering.

Comment: Indeed, I've redrawn that picture a bit for net force being complied to [vector addition rules](https://i.ibb.co/3rvMqBW/projections.png).